# stacking images in a last modification timeline using linux command line and imagemagick, convert -append double stacking my images

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, imagemagick

I am trying to create an image timeline (vertical) of a set of images stored in all subdirectories of a given directory (stacked in last modification order)

```
#!/bin/bash/

find $1 -name "*.jpg"  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n"|sort -n|cut -f3 -d" ">junk9090.txt

echo $1.jpg|tr / _ >> junk9090.txt

convert -append $(cat junk9090.txt)

rm junk9090.txt
```

When the image is outputted it stacks them in order except the last image and then it stacks the first n-1 images again.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suc7p.jpg)

[Output from my bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsAMJ.jpg)

Comment: Try `convert -append @junk9090.txt result.jpg` instead of your penultimate line.

Comment: `@Mark Setchell` A minor point here, proper Imagemagick syntax would be to read the input(s) before applying -append as: `convert @junk9090.txt -append result.jpg`. But IM 6 is rather forgiving, so it likely will not matter the order. However, that is not true for IM 7. It is more strict on following proper syntax